# How to fix 'non-numeric argument to mathematical function'

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series

I am totally new in R and doing an assignment for my studies. While coding I found an error stating "non-numeric argument to mathematical function". I Know the header is causing it, as it is the only non-numeric character in the database. But I don't know how to fix it.

I tried to calculate excluding the header, but couldn't do it.

```
DF = read.csv("Nominal Broad Dollar Index Modified.csv", header = TRUE)
head(DF)
```

This is the head of my data frame, & I'm not sure where the x1 column came and whether it is causing the error.

[image]

```
Index = DF$Index
Index0 = Index[DF$Y < 2018]
R0 = diff(log(Index0))
```

> Error in log(Index0) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function

there are no results, I'm just getting errors.

Comment: Firstly, please do not include pictures of data in your question, add the data using `dput`. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Then, you do not have a column named `Index` in your data set so `DF$Index` would return NULL.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Column `X.1` will be the result of a dispensable separator at the end of each line in your csv file (but that and also the column names won't cause the error - as already stated by @LyzandeR, the problem is how you are trying to access the data).

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys. My problem is solved. :)

Comment: As a general rule, I would also recommend using `read_csv` (or something like it) from the tidyverse package `readr`